# How to represent array with nested arrays as an object

Tags: javascript, object

This is my code

```
let array = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['gender', 'female'],
  ],
  [
    ['lastName', 'Kim'],
    ['age', 40],
    ['gender', 'female'],
  ],  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['gender', 'male'],
  ],
]

array.map(function (el) {
   return Object.assign({}, el)
})
```

However this is how it appears in the console

[image]

I've tried `array.flat()` but did not work as intended

I want the result to look something like this

```
[[{firstName : 'Mary'}.{lastName : 'jenkins'},..],...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want a list of objects, or a list of a list of key-value (pair) objects?

### List of objects

```js
let array = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['gender', 'female'],
  ],
  [
    ['lastName', 'Kim'],
    ['age', 40],
    ['gender', 'female'],
  ],  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['gender', 'male'],
  ],
]

const listOfObjects = array.map(Object.fromEntries);

console.log(listOfObjects.map(JSON.stringify).join('\n'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### List of list of object properties

```js
let array = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['gender', 'female'],
  ],
  [
    ['lastName', 'Kim'],
    ['age', 40],
    ['gender', 'female'],
  ],  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['gender', 'male'],
  ],
]

const listOfListOfPairs = array.map(items =>
  items.map(item =>
    Object.fromEntries([item])));

console.log(listOfListOfPairs.map(JSON.stringify).join('\n'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Object.fromEntries`.

in your case something like this would work:

```js
let array = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['gender', 'female'],
  ],
  [
    ['lastName', 'Kim'],
    ['age', 40],
    ['gender', 'female'],
  ],  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['gender', 'male'],
  ],
]

const asObjects = array.map((entries) => Object.fromEntries(entries))
console.log(asObjects)
```